# изменение масштаба

Tags: css

Подскажите, при изменении масштаба некоторые блоки "уезжают".

Мне надо прописывать `margin: auto`

[сайт](http://31042.www7.site/04/)

Comment: Тебе надо прописывать width в процентах

Comment: Для начала нужно прочитать хоть что-то о верстке!!! 
Потом добавить: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
Упорядочить html!
Убрать ОШИБКИ в CSS! Это для начала...

Answer (score 0):

Примените **[viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)** + **[размеры](http://viewportsizes.com/)**, как вам рекомендовала в комментариях Elena Semenchenko. Укажите размеры в %, а не в px. Если необходимы статичные размеры, то примените **em** и/или **rem** - **[инфо W3](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)** + **[ещё инфо W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)**